Missing code generation templates and language option 'Use the new Statemachine Template'
I have problem with code generation / model configuration in Enterprise Architect v15.2.
The problem regards to all code generation languages.
After first installation of EA in May 2023 the configuration of source code generation for state machines was possible without any restrictions. Even definition of source code teamplates works fine.
Some weeks ago, first problems regarding code generaton occured.
I lost all 'STM' templates code generation templates.
Today I have re-installed EA completely but templates are still missing.
When I check model configuration, also model option 'Use the new Statemachine Template' is unavailable.
How can I fix the problem? EA v15.2 is mandatory for my current project.
Additional Details :
Following items are missing in my EA 15.2 installation

entry of Start - Desktop - Preferences - Source Code Engineering - C or C++ - UseNewStatemachineTemplate
all behavior code templates at Develop - Preferences - Options - Edit Code Templates for all languages
all langage setting for Develop - Preferences - Options - Edit Code Templates with name like "STM".

Thanks for your support.

update 29.04.2024
@Geert
Many thanks for your hints. Nevertheless problems still remains. I tried to re-install v15.2 again without any success.

I noticed that user preferences and custom SQL searches ramains after re-install. Why - and where are this data stored.
Attached please find some screenshots
Code templated orderd by name corrupt installation

Code template from second installation

Query to t_template table on corrupt installation is empty


Please add more details about the actual problem. What do you see? Do you have any errors,... Be specific, and add printscreens where appropriate.

Stefan, please add the details in the question, not in the comments.

Error found !!!!
Thanks to everybody, esp. @Geert.
The problem was solved by checking shared licence.
It was obviously changed from Ultimate to Corporate.
May be admin changed configuration without my knowledge.

if the answer solved the problem you can indicate that with the checkmark, awarding me the imaginary internet points ;)

I think you are looking at the wrong place.
I found this option in the model preferences Configure | Model | Options, while you seem to be looking at your personal preferences

I don't seem to have any STM templates either, but I do have templates for both behavior as State Machines, but the set of templates doesn't seem to be affected by the option Use the new Statemachine Template

The standard templates seem to be stored in the file C:\Program Files (x86)\Sparx Systems\EA\TemplateResources161.dll
Once you edit an existing template, or create a new one, this is stored in the model in the table t_template
Generating code from behavioral models is only enabled in the Ultimate and Unified editions of EA

See https://sparxsystems.com/products/ea/compare-editions.html for more info.

Dear Geert, Unfurtunatelly I'm looking an the right place. Exacly all this entries are gone !!!! The instalation of EA 15.2 on a different computer works well and all entries are available. The question is why this happens!!!! After re-installation I expect all system entries to be resetted. I removed all EA directories and even registry entries, but the error still remains.  Any idea ?

I added some details about where to look for the templates. It might help you you post an image of exactly what you are seeing in this other installation, that you aren't seeing on yours.
